# Topological Sort on Neo4j

Tags: ruby, rest, graph-theory, neo4j, topological-sort

I have a graph on neo4j and I would like to run a topological sort, preferably without writing on the graph itself (to allow for multiple clients to run algorithms on the same graph simultaneously).

How should I approach this? Shall I clone the graph and work on the temporary copy, or is there a sort of traversal/iterator ?

thanks

PS: I'm using neo4J through the neography gem (REST API) on Ruby

Comment: How big is the graph? I would consider cloning the graph, and do batch operations on it, but it depends on your setup and context ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan,

You can start a transaction and fail it once you have the data you need so it won't write to the database.  See http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/21/max-flow-with-gremlin-and-transactions/ for an example.  This won't work too well if you have to touch a million nodes, but for small subsets of the graph it should be no problem.

Comment: thanks Max! also, neography is a great gem. I am doing what you suggest and using RGL to do the topological sort on-memory.